# How to uninstall Umbraco 7

Tags: nuget, uninstallation, umbraco7

I installed Umbraco 7.2.2. from the latest [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/7.2.2). However, annoyingly I just clicked **install** from the initial install wizard, as shown below.

[image: umbraco 7 installer - step 1]

Unknowingly it wouldnt ask me for the DB connections. So my question is. Is there a clean way to revert the installation and start again. Or am I just best to delete the project and install the NuGet package again?

Im aware of earlier versions that I could just remove the appsetting value below and it would start the installer again.

```
<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="7.2.2" />
```

---

#### EDIT:

**This is no longer the case. Removing the value from the above app settings only looks to upgrade the installation.**

---

However I dont want to be left with a bloated Umbraco install with redundant files, like the .sdf DB etc. Or is it the case that the normal install doesnt actually include many additional files than the custom install? And its just the SDF?

The more I write this the more it makes sense to just start again with a fresh project. :)

Keen to hear an opinion regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the current site as it is installed now and go to the backoffice (`http://yoursite.local/umbraco`). Go to the developer section > Packages > Installed Packages > Fanoe. Go to the Uninstall Package tab and confirm the uninstall.

In your web.config set `umbracoConfigurationStatus` to an empty string:

`<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="" />`

And set the connection string to the default empty values:

```
<remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="" providerName="" />
```

After saving this file, your application pool will recycle and you can delete the umbraco.sdf file from the App_Data folder. In fact you can delete everything in App_Data.

As you said, it would be much easier to delete the current site and just start over, choosing "Customize" during the next install.

Comment: yeah as i wrote the question the more it became obvious for me to just start the install over. But for a point of reference i thought i would retain the question. Thanks for your comment.